# Laravel App\Http\Middleware\Class not found

Tags: laravel

Just migrated my Laravel app from a local environment to a online development environment on a remote server. After this migration I am getting an error:

```
ReflectionException thrown with message "Class App\Http\MiddleWare\NotUser does not exist"
```

I've deleted the `vendor` folder, as well as `composer.lock` and ran `composer update`. Also cleared `bootstrap/cache` and also tried running`php artisan config:clear`.

Purged all `cache/*` files from storage. Whenever I attempt to log in to the dashboard, I receive the error that middleware does not exist.

**app/Http/Middleware/NotUser.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class NotUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        # This middleware prevents anyone who is not an admin from accessing given route or controller
        # apply by using it in the constructor, $this->middleware('is.admin');
        if ($request->user()->role->name === 'user') {
            return back()->with('error', __('Access denied'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
'not.user' => \App\Http\MiddleWare\NotUser::class
];
```

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['not.user', 'auth']], function () { ... }
```

This works fine on locally hosted environment. I had no problems. After I switched to a development environment I started receiving this error and I have no idea what's causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is case sensitive I believe, so change this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
'not.user' => \App\Http\MiddleWare\NotUser::class
];
```

to this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
'not.user' => \App\Http\Middleware\NotUser::class
];
```

Notice the capital `W` in `Middleware`.

Comment: Damn, nice catch! It appears my dev server is much more strict on this than my local one.