# Target Class [Facade\Ignition\Middleware\AddJobInformation] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

In the local server application is running properly but in the production server I'm getting such issue.

Comment: add your ``app/Http/Kernel.php`` codes

Comment: Possibly, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56783977/5882307

Comment: Please check `camel case` in your model name

Comment: Sorry to be that guy but this question is not answerable. We are not magician, there are thousands of possible causes to this issue and the only clue is "working in local but not in production". You have to help us help you by providing code sample, what you already tried, how you deploy to production...

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php artisan optimize:clear` ,
If that doesn't work, try `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I have already tried with this one. Its not working...